# How do I make my bar chart's height be the data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I made a bar chart from data from a .csv file. I am struggling to make the height of the bar chart. I would like the height to be taken from the data values of a specific column, in this case, the "NO OF RECORDS STOLEN" column in the file.

I have tried things like:

```
.attr("height", function(d) {return d["NO OF RECORDS STOLEN"];}
```

but it does not work.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bar Chart | Crime File</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dataset = "data_breaches.csv";

        var w = 960;
        var h = 500;
        var barPadding = 1;
        var barWidth = w / dataset.length - barPadding;

        // create canvas
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

        // create bar chart
        svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                return i * (barWidth + barPadding);
            })
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", barWidth)
            .attr("height", 100) // WORKING ON THIS
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                return "rgb(200, 50, 50)";
            });


        // get data
        d3.csv(dataset, function (data) {

            // convert type from string to integer
            data.forEach(function typeConv(d) {
                // type conversion from string to number
                d["YEAR"] = +d["YEAR"]; // for names with spaces
                d["DATA SENSITIVITY"] = +d["DATA SENSITIVITY"];
                d["NO OF RECORDS STOLEN"] = +d["NO OF RECORDS STOLEN"];
                return d;
            });

            var arrayLength = data.length;

            // fixed, should have been <, not <= bc n-1, not n
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                var breachesData = data[i];
                console.log(breachesData);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This code will produce nothing. The drawing part, which relies on `data`, has to be **inside** `d3.csv`. Also, the loop is useless.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment at your question, you need to append the rectangles **after** the data is loaded. Also I reviewed your code and removed unnecessary parts for clarity. Pay attention to the comments that I've added and let us know if you have any questions. Good luck!

```
var dataset = "data_breaches.csv";

var w = 960;
var h = 500;
var barPadding = 1;
var barWidth = w / dataset.length - barPadding;

// create canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

// get data
d3.csv(dataset, function (data) {
    // You need to create a "scale" to convert from your data values to pixels in the screen
    var heightBy = "NO OF RECORDS STOLEN"
    var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(d => d[heightBy])])
        .range([0, h])

    // create bar chart
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data) // "dataset" is the filepath, "data" is the loaded file content
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", (d, i) => i * (barWidth + barPadding))
        .attr("y", d => h - scale(d[heightBy])) // Remember that on SVG y=0 is at the bottom and the rect height grows down
        .attr("width", barWidth)
        .attr("height", d => scale(d[heightBy]))
        .attr("fill", "rgb(200, 50, 50)");
});
```